# Firebase android app setup never finishes the 'communicated with our servers' step

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to complete Firebase setup, I'm following the simple steps included with Firebase console, however, the final step where the app should communicate with Firebase never finishes.

I've tried deleting the app from Firebase and doing the setup again, I've downloaded the config file multiple times with no luck. I've deleted and re-installed the app also with no luck.

I've done all the following steps:

Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):

```
    buildscript {
      dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
      }
    }
```

App-level build.gradle (//build.gradle):

```
    dependencies {
      // Add this line
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    }
    ...
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Once this is complete I hope to see app analytics for this app in the dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried to skip that step and see in your project actually runs?

Comment: Hi Alex, what do you mean? The app runs without problems, but I never get any analytics on Firebase. Not sure if its somewhat related I have an IOS version of the app for which the analytics work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```